# S3 : Put Vs Multipart Notification clarification

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, aws-amplify

Wanted to confirm the behavior I am seeing. I am using Amplify.Storage.uploadFile to upload a file. The file being uploaded can be of any size . Seems like the amplify sdk decides the mechanism for upload depending upon file size. I am listening to SQS notifications on upload. This is the behavior that I see

Enable only Multipart upload complete notification:

1. Smaller file size : receive nothing
2. Larger file size: receive single ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload event

Problem: I miss out on the smaller file.

Enable both PUT and Multipart upload complete notification

1. Smaller file size: receive put event
2. Larger file size : get multiple ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload events

Problem: I don’t know which of the notifications to listen to for the larger file size.  I don’t know if anything is guaranteed about the timing of the multiple notification.  Can I assume to try to read the file and if the multipart upload has not truly finished then I wouldn’t be able to download the file and hence I can ignore the notification ?

Thoughts ?

Comment: If you enable put  ( which I need to  in order to detect smaller files being uploaded) along with multipart upload then you get multiple ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload events.

Comment: Are you sure that in case of multipart uploads you get multiple S3 events corresponding to each part? 

I don't use Amplify.Storage, but when I play around with [multipart uploads in AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/), I get only one event "ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload" at the end after `aws s3api complete-multipart-upload`. 

Ironically I'd like to receive events after completion of each part (`aws s3api upload-part`)